# Trying to uninstall Visual Studio Enterpise 2019 but getting error

Tags: visual-studio

Uninstalling Visual Studio Enterprise results in the following error:

```
048c:0012][2021-01-01T21:52:35] Error 0x80131500: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: $. Path ''.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Serialization.ModelSerializer`1.Deserialize(TextReader reader)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.DirectoryRepository.GetPackage(IPackageIdentity identity)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.GetPackage(IPackageIdentity identity)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.Extensions.IsPayloadRequired(IInstallablePackage package, ExecuteAction action, IServiceProvider services, ExecuteAction bootstrapperAction)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.CreateDownloadInstallActivities(InstallablePackage installable, ExecuteAction action, Boolean isPresent)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.PlanInstallable(InstallablePackage installable, Dictionary`2 downloadLookup, PackagePlan& packagePlan, Boolean repairPackagesWithDuplicateFiles, Boolean upgradeConfigurationPackage)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Plan()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Schedule()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.CreateInstallOperation(Product product, String destination, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Uninstall(CancellationToken token)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Seems like the `Path` was nothing, see those double apostrophes, they contain nothing in mean.

Comment: Why are you tagging C++ or C# as this is not a programming related question?

Comment: Just a note: The application is installed into my D drive and I have tried all the troubleshooting methods on the Microsoft website and I am not using the command line

Comment: ok, so you are uninstalling it from visual studio installer?

Comment: yes maytham im using the installer

Comment: @Straughz hmmm, it is quite interesting. this need some rethinking. I will try to see what I can bring more :)

Comment: I managed to get it uninstalled. I used something called IOBit Uninstaller and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You are trying uninstall Visual Studio via command line and you are not passing the right path of Visual Studio Enterprise:

```
vs_enterprise.exe uninstall --installPath <Visual Studio installation location>
```

For documentation [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and check [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/668804/how-to-uninstall-vs2019-enterprice-from-cmd-or-dev.html).

I also suggest if you have issue with it you can use Visual Studio Installer.

[image]